# Why Hartree-Fock study is done in integer fillings rather than any arbitrary fillings?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory, many-body

I have seen a lot of papers where people study interacting electrons with Hartree-Fock approximation at integer fillings only. Just to mention a few:

1. [Twisted bilayer graphene III. Interacting Hamiltonian and exact symmetries](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.12376)
2. [TSTG II: Projected Hartree-Fock Study of Twisted Symmetric Trilayer Graphene](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14905)
3. [Kekulé spiral order at all nonzero integer fillings in twisted bilayer graphene](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.05857)

In these papers the electronic system is a twisted bilayer (or trilayer) graphene, which has 4-fold degeneracy (2 valley x 2 spin). So, filling those 4 band means putting 4 particles in the unit cell. In all the studies mentioned above they only consider non-zero integer fillings such as $\nu = \pm(1,2,3)$ for the Hartree-Fock study.

Whereas, if I think about Jellium model, all the text book present calculations with any arbitrary filling factor (or $k_F$). I think part of the reason is that there is nothing like integer filling for this continuum model of Jellium model as the band structure is not periodic.

**If I want to study Hartree-Fock at some fractional fillings, what holds me from doing that?**

Answer (score 2):

In some systems there can be states of interest at integer fillings, such as the correlated insulator states of twisted bilayer graphene. Maybe that's the reason these authors focus on those cases.

Moreover, in 3D bulk materials filling is generally not controllable except through chemical doping, so the case of interest is often half-filling (which is integer).

Beyond this, there is nothing preventing you from making a HF calculation at non-integer filling. [Here is](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.01178) an example to illustrate that.